# Two identical javascript buttons, one works and the other don't

Tags: javascript, php, dygraphs

I have a php function that echos 2 js scripts, each script creates a button that once clicked draw an image and download it. The problem is that the first button works (draw and download) and the second doesn't (only draw) although they are both identical code and no errors in console, can someone help and point out what is wrong here.

```
function download_button($mabez_blades)
{

echo <<<TEST
        <script type="text/javascript" src="dygraph-extra.js"></script>


        <img id="img" style="width:1000px; height:300px;" alt="image first"/>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="300" >canvas</canvas>
        <button type="button" onclick="saveImage()">save image</button>

        <script type="text/javascript">

           function plotimg() {
                var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
                var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                var img = document.getElementById("img");
                Dygraph.Export.asPNG(gSC_2_1, img);
                ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            };

            function saveImage() {
                plotimg()

                    var link = document.createElement('a');
                    link.download = "test.png";
                    link.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
                    console.log(link.href);
                    link.click();
                    };
        </script>


TEST;

echo <<<KKK

    <img id="img1"  style="width:1000px; height:300px;" alt="image second"/>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1000" height="300">myCanvas</canvas>
    <button type="button" onclick="downloadCanvas()">Download Pictures</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function drawcanvas() {
        var canvas1 = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx1 = canvas1.getContext("2d");
        var img1 = document.getElementById("img1")
        Dygraph.Export.asPNG(gSC_2_1, img1);
        ctx1.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
    };

    function downloadCanvas() {
    drawcanvas() 
    var link1 = document.createElement('b');
    link1.download = "experment.png";
    link1.href = myCanvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
    console.log(link1.href);
    link1.click();
        };

        </script>
KKK;



}
```

Comment: Have you found any error in console ?

Answer (score 1):

Not the same

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
```

vs

```
var link1 = document.createElement('b');
```

an `<a>` (anchor) element DOES have href attribue that does something

a `<b>` (bold) element does not

Comment: Thank you for your help, this was not a smart mistake.